# How to move a textbox with mouse click in Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app

Tags: c#, animation, uwp, textbox, user-controls

I am trying to move a `textbox` that is the child of a Canvas by clicking and dragging with a mouse or touching and dragging on a windows Surface device. I have tried using TextBox.Manipulation data, as well as PointerPressed, PointerMoved and PointerReleased but none of these have proven successful. Are there any suggestions for how to use either of these methods of moving a text box? Or, are there any suggestions using a different approach?

Thanks

Comment: `InkCanvas.SetLeft( myTextBox, someLeftValue ); InkCanvas.SetTop( myTextBox, someTopValue );`

Comment: Yes, but how do I detect when a mouse clicks on the text box and at what position to move it to?

Comment: When a mouse is clicked, handle the click event and get the left and top co-ordinates of the click point from the event arguments. Search for wpf mouse click event examples online.

Comment: UWP mouse clicks are handled differently than WPF. Do you know of a way that is handled in both?

Answer (score 1):

XAML Manipulation mode needs to be set.

```
ManipulationMode="TranslateX, TranslateY"
ManipulationDelta="SomeControl_ManipulationDelta"
```

Then code behind.

```
private void SomeControl_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var uiEle = sender as UIElement;
        var change = e.Delta.Translation;
        var left = Canvas.GetLeft(uiEle);
        var top = Canvas.GetTop(uiEle);
        left += change.X;
        top += change.Y;
        Canvas.SetLeft(uiEle, left);
        Canvas.SetTop(uiEle, top);
    }
```

The above sample is from vs2017 with target/min of build 16299.

The code provided doesn't prevent dragging off screen so you may want to implement a clamp mechanism for the new left and top values or some other means of preventing the control being dropped in non visible space.